# How base of isosceles triangle change with change in height

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

An isosceles triangle has height $15 \text{ cm}$ with respect to unequal side. It's height is diminished to $5 \text{ cm}$ keeping equal side constant so that the base increases. How much the base is increased??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot tell. Let $x$ be the length of the equal sides and let $2b$ be the base when the height is 15 and $2B$ be the base when the height is 5.

Then 
$$
x^2 = 15^2 + b^2 = 5^2 + B^2.
$$
Hence
$$
B-b = \sqrt{x^2-5^2}-\sqrt{x^2-15^2}
$$
which is not constant in $x$.

Comment: But the increased length should be unique.So there should be a way

Comment: @Anonymous $B-b$ depends by the length of the equal sides, so it is not unique in this sense.